# Why is C#'s random lower limit inclusive, but upper limit exclusive?

Tags: c#, random

Take this code for example:

```
Random rnd = new Random();
int rndNumber = rnd.Next(0,101);
```

**One would expect that either one of the following would happen:**
-rndNumber contains a random integer between 0 and 101
-rndNumber contains a random integer between 1 and 100

What actually happens though, is that rndNumber contains a random integer between 0 and 100. Why is this the case?

I understand that the upper limit is exclusive, but then why is the lower limit inclusive? Why is this not consistent?

Comment: "Why is this not consistent?" - consistent with *what*? In a great many problem areas it's desirable to use a semi-open interval.

Comment: IOW are you asking why ranges are asymetric? Consider that N-element array has elements with indices in range [0;N) too.

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever Consistent with itself. I would expect both parameters to be either inclusive or exclusive. Could you elaborate your point in an answer?

Comment: Surely because all random number generator functions before C# worked that way.  In turn inspired by the way the % operator works.

Comment: It is consistent with `Random.NextDouble()` where it does makes sense that 0.0 is inclusive and 1.0 is exclusive.

Comment: @Dennis_E: I'm not sure it's correct to generally say that it "makes sense that 0.0 is inclusive and 1.0 is exclusive". I can well think of situations where that is actually not desired, and the retrieved random number is supposed to actually span the full continuous range from, say, 0% to 100% (both inclusive).

Comment: @O.R.Mapper OK, you got a point there.

Comment: @Dennis_E And then it becomes quite complex to generate 0...1 inclusive... And I'll add that I wouldn't ever use the `Random.NextDouble()` for anything serious... How is it calculated? Do the various subranges of 0...1 (0-0.1, 0.1-0.2...) have the same possibility of being generated? (`double` are a strange format in the end)... And what if I want `0...1` inclusive? It is perhaps better to generate numbers in the range 0...1000000 (inclusive) and the divide 1.0 / generated number

Comment: @xanatos `Random.NextDouble()` gets a 'sample' then divides by `Int32.MaxValue` [(link to the source code)](http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/system/random.cs,62cd8ffb36191d74), so the distribution **is** uniform (within the confines of the random number generation algorithm, at least) in the interval [0, 1).

Comment: @WaiHaLee That alone doesn't show anything . `double` are denser the nearer you are to 0 (at least from what I know). Still it works (see http://ideone.com/SC0eez you must run it on your pc), because in the full range [0, 1) they do maintain a density greater than necessary. On the density, for example for `float` (that work in the same way than `double` but are "faster" to enumerate), there are 1036831949 possible value in the range [0;0.1), while there are only 1677721 in the range [0.9;1) (see http://ideone.com/I20yDE)

Comment: @xanatos I see what you're saying. `NextDouble` will **never** return a value in the range (0, 1 / `Int32.MaxValue`). Would you want it to return **any** number (including, say, [`Double.Epsilon`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.double.epsilon)) in the range [0, 1) where the probability of returning, say, exactly `0.5` is twice the probability of returning exactly `0.25` (since the sub-interval of [0, 1) which is best represented by `0.5` is larger than the sub-interval in [0, 1) which is best represented by `0.25`)? That **would** be better.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

This approach is consistent with numbering schemes that use zero as their initial element. This is convenient in several situations, because you do not have to do any arithmetic or face rare off-by-one errors, for example

**When you pick a random element of an array:**

```
var rndElement = myArray[rnd.Next(0, myArray.Length)];
```

**When you split an interval at several points, and pick random elements from each sub-interval:**

```
var endpoints = new[] {0, 10, 17, 36, 80};
for (int i = 0 ; i+1 < endpoints.Length ; i++) {
    var from = endpoints[i];
    var to = endpoints[i+1];
    Console.WriteLine("({0}..{1}) : {2}", from , to, rnd.Next(from, to));
}
```

It also makes it easier to compute how many different values can be generated.

Comment: The only limitation is that generating random numbers inclusive of `int.MaxValue` is a little complex :-) (especially if you want the full range `int.MinValue` - `int.MaxValue`)

Comment: @xanatos raises a good point - getting a random `int` over the whole range **is** tricky. One way of doing it is with [`Random.NextBytes`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.random.nextbytes) and [`BitConverter.ToInt32`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.bitconverter.toint32) but that seems messy.

Comment: @dasblinkenlight `(int)rnd.NextLong(0, 1L + int.MaxValue)` There is no overload that accepts long values for `Random`.